# Нужна ли запятая в "с самого начала у меня была какая-то тактика, и я ее придерживался"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении:

- С самого начала у меня была какая-то тактика, и я ее придерживался.

Answer (score 4):

Запятая перед *и,да(в значении «и»),или, либо* не ставится,если части сложносочиненного предложения имеют общий второстепенный член или вводное слово (словосочетание). Здесь таковым является **с самого начала**.

> С самого начала у меня была какая‐то тактика и я ее придерживался.

Розенталь Справочник по русскому языку.ХХУ11 §104.2а.

> Несмотря на распространившиеся слухи, газеты обходили этот вопрос молчанием и мы продолжали ждать.

Answer (score 2):

Уверен, что нужна.
Это предложение состоит из двух независимых частей ([Сложносочинённое предложение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)):

1. тактика *(подлежащее)* ... была *(сказуемое)*.
2. я *(подлежащее)* ... придерживался *(сказуемое)*.

Я в таких случаях использую следующее "бытовое" правило: если вместо запятой поставить точку, и в результате смысл не изменится, то запятая нужна.